# Input to an executable in bash script

Tags: bash, input, terminal, sh

I am using a bash file to automate a process that I do in the terminal. Part of it is calling a function `~/Executables/postprocessor` that asks for an input `MyFileName`. In the terminal, I do it like this, and works fine:

```
[user SimulationFolder]$ ~/Executables/postprocessor
Project name = first part of filenames >
MyFileName
```

When I put it in bash like:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/bin/activate_enviroment.sh

~/Executables/postprocessor
MyFileName
```

I get the error `MyFileName: command not found`, so `MyFileName` is interpreted as a bash command instead of the input for the function.

**How do I make the bash introduce this input?** (note that this is NOT a USER input, I know the value every time, and should be done directly from the bash)

I also tried

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/bin/activate_enviroment.sh

~/Executables/postprocessor MyFileName
```

And the postprocessor simply didn't run because it didn't receive an input

Comment: Just to be clear, I want to confirm that you're asking about bash (which is Linux-exclusive) and not batch (which is Windows-exclusive). Because you've written a bash script and gotten a bash error, but you've said the word "batch" multiple times and used the [batch-file] tag.

Comment: You can try `~/Executables/postprocessor <<<'MyFileName'`

Comment: I think the syntax you probably want is "~/Executables/postprocessor $MyFileName" in order to correctly get the file name value. Also, if you want to see what the script is parsing in more detail, you can use "#!/bin/bash -x" at the start of your script

Comment: There are already 2 answers in the comments: the page provided via the link is listing several possibilities.
My pref would have been  ```( sleep 2 ; printf 'MyFilename' ) | ~/Executables/postprocessor```

Comment: @Jayjargot, ...what's the point of the `sleep`? And that printf doesn't provide a trailing newline; assuming someone typing at a prompt presses enter after it, you want `printf '%s\n' 'MyFilename' | ...`; that also lets you provide multiple lines of input (`printf '%s\n' 'Line One' 'Line Two'`)

Comment: @Mr.Grasses, mind, you _should_ modify your `postprocessor` to read its argv and, if it finds a name on the argument list, not prompt from stdin; that's proper practice, though as you've shown us it isn't written to follow that practice now.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: we do not know the command's implementation. sometimes the standard input is cleared before a read (so that the string is lost) isn't it?, or sometimes the standard input is read after a delay?. To cope with these situations, a ```sleep``` could make the trick.

Comment: @Jayjargot, those are very exceptional situations; well-behaved software doesn't do those things (in part _because_ that kind of practice would prevent that software from being able to read from a pipe, FIFO, etc); and even when it _is_ done, a sensible implementation will check `isatty()` and only go ahead with the clear operation when input is connected to a terminal as opposed to a file/FIFO/socket/etc. I'm not going to say never _ever_ necessary, but I can comfortably say that it's so rare that adding latency/runtime _just in case_ it might happen isn't sensible.